# how to make a mysql query and turn it into an array in php

Tags: php, mysql

if I have a query that looks like this in php...

```
if ($result3 = $connuser->query("SELECT * FROM devices WHERE uid='".$username."'")){
    
}
```

How can I turn $result3 into an array?
Also, separate question, I tried doing

```
echo $result3;
```

but it doesn't work. Is there a way to view $result3 so I can see what it looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$rows = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I still want to view it though. When I do echo $rows; it simply says arrayTable. I want to know it's length and what is in it.

Comment: You could use: `print_r($rows);` or `var_dump($rows);` for a quick look, or loop through `$rows` if you want to format it nicely.  `echo` is for showing strings, not arrays.

Comment: or just `$rows = $result3->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Comment: Thanks both work fine, however, my array comes back in this format...  ex(for index position2)        [2]=> NULL ["d2"]=> NULL. When I change index 2 it doesn't change the ["d2"] How can I do this in my loop?

Comment: nevermind I found it. I used mysqli_fetch_row instead. Thanks guys